show that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
The problem
Let the convex quadrilateral $ABCD, M=$ the midpoint of $BC, N=$ the midpoint of $CD$ and ${P}=AM \cap BN$. If $\frac{AP}{PM}=4, \frac{BP}{PN}=\frac{2}{3}$ then show that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
my idea
drawing

As you can see on the drawing I let $O=$ the middle of AC, ${E}=BO \cap AM$ and got that E is the centre of gravity of triangle ABC, ${F}= DM \cap BN$ and got that F is the centre of gravity of the triangle BDC, ${Y}=BN \cap AC$ and as you can see I noted and expressed some of the sides as: $AE=10X, EP=2X,PM=3X,PB =6Y, FP=4Y, NF=5Y$
By the propriety of the center of gravity we get that $EF || AD, AD=3EF$
If we show that $Y=F$ we would be able to show that in triangle $OBC$ we have $FE||BC, 3EF=BC$ and we would prove what we wanted.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

I suspect that proving $Y=F$ is equivalent to proving that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. Why would $AC, BN, DM$ be concurrent otherwise? It's not that clear how these relate to $P$ and the ratios.

My second approach, with the intention of avoiding Menelaus, which turned out to be much faster.
Let $O$ be the midpoint of $BN$.
$OM \parallel NC$ by midpoints.
$BP: PO:ON = 4:1:5$, and $AP:PM = 4:1$ so $AB \parallel OM$.
Thus $AB \parallel CD$, so let's track their lengths.
$OM  = \frac{1}{2} NC = \frac{ 1}{4} AB$ and $NC = \frac{1}{2} AB$, so $ AB = CD$.
Thus, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.

My first approach - Since we only have ratio of lengths, I decided to apply Menelaus where I could.
Let $E$ be a point on $CD$ extended such that $DC = CE$.
Observe that $\frac{BP}{PN}\cdot \frac{ NE}{EC} \cdot \frac{ CM}{BM} = \frac{ 2}{3} \cdot \frac{ 3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1} = 1$, so by Menelaus on triangle $BNC$, $APEM$ is a straight line.
Apply Menelaus to triangle $BPM$ and transversal $NCE$, we get that $ \frac{ BN}{NP} \cdot \frac{ PE}{EM} \cdot \frac{MC}{CB} = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{PE}{EM}  = \frac{6}{5} \Rightarrow \frac{PM}{ME} = \frac{1}{5} $.
So $AP: PM: ME = 4:1:5$, which shows that $M$ is the midpoint of $AE$.
In quadrilateral $ABCE$, since $M$ is the midpoint of the diagonals $AE$ and $BC$, hence $ABEC$ is a parallelogram.
Since $DC = CE$, hence $ABCD$ is a paraellegoram.


Let us construct a parallelogram $ABCD’$ using the sides $AB$ and $BC$. We will show that the points $D$ and $D’$ are actually the same. We also construct mid-points of the sides as shown in the figure.

It can be easily shown that this construction satisfies the following side ratios:

The point $P’$ divides $AM$ in a $4:1$ ratio. Thus the point $P’$ is identical to the point $P$.
$BP:PX =BP’:P’X=2:3=BP:PN$, thus showing that the point $X$ is identical to the point $N$.
$CN:ND’=CX:XD’=1:1=CN:ND$, thus showing that the point $D’$ is identical to the point $D$.
Thus $ABCD$ is proved to be a parallelogram.
Note: I had posted the parallelogram length-ratio idea here previously, but thanks to Calvin Lin for helping to turn that into an answer.
